# Data fetching from graphql server with ApolloClient doesn t work. How can I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Here, I am creating new ApolloClient with graphql

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client"

const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

export default client
```

Then I create a context of ApolloProvider

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {ApolloProvider} from "@apollo/client"
import client from "./common/apollo-client"
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from "./redux/index"
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[image: Here is making a query in playground on https://localhost:4000/graphql]

Here the same query in code

```
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client"

const GET_CATEGORIES = gql`
    {
        categories {
            name
        }
    }
`

export default function useGetCategories() {
    const {data} = useQuery(GET_CATEGORIES)
    return data
}
```

Then I trying to use this hook in a functional component, but it logs UNDEFINED

```
export default function Mainpage() {
    const categories = useGetCategories()

    console.log(categories)
    

    return (
        <Header />
    )
}
```

I tried to restart backend on localhost:4000, but it didn't help. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with you are using customHook and that is the promise for graphql what it does is return the instance of that current runtime and it is undefined at that time all you can do is simply use in the component that you want to use why are you complexing things.

```
export default function Mainpage() {
    const {loading,data,error} = useQuery(GET_CATEGORIES)
    // first data will be undefined and when the promise resolved it will console data
    console.log(data,{data})
    console.log(loading,{loading})
    console.log(error,{error})
    
    return (
        <Header />
    )
}
```

but if you still want to use customHook for graph you can do it like this.

```
  const [getCategories] = useLazyQuery(
    GET_CATEGORIES
  );
  const [data, setData] = useState()

  useEffect(async() => {
    try {
      const res = await getCategories()
      setData(res)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error: ', err)
    }
  }, [])

  return data
```

Comment: Can you recommend what is better? What is better in production for example, using the custom hook or just useQuery in component in this situation?

Comment: useQuery simple until or unless if your component has to many logic related to `data` then you move you logic into `customHook` and do all the logic there but for this case use it in the component because i didn't see any complex logic that will extend your component line's of code.